# Can I reuse the data presented in a datatable?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, datatables

I have a flask application that makes a call to my API to pull down some records. I then pass the json response to json2html, then to datatables to create a table. I plan on creating a button on my table with row select option.

My question is, can I use the data on my table to populate a form on another page? Effectively I want to be able to select the row, click update button which takes me to a form page with the form values populated from the row values. So if click row 1, and my form page with be populated,

```
id = 6a3d7026-43f3-67zt-9211-99dfc6fee82e
name = test
description = test
number = 20934120
....some other fields not from the table
```

I am not sure how I can achieve this without a database. Not looking for a full solution just some pointers on the best methods or some good documentation. Thanks

**example response**

```
{'count': 2, 'total': 2, 
'data': [
{'id': '6a3d7026-43f3-67zt-9211-99dfc6fee82e', 
 'name': 'test',  
 'properties': {'Description#en': 'test', 'Number#en': '20934120'},
{'id': '6a3d7026-43f3-67zt-9211-99hdttbhh4ed', 
 'name': 'test',  
 'properties': {'Description#en': 'test', 'Number#en': '20934121'}}],
```

**inside app.py**

```
 ....REQUEST
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    output = json2html.convert(json = data, table_attributes="id=\"table1\" class=\"table1\")
    return render_template("update.html", data=data, output=output)
```

**inside update.html**

```
{{output|safe}}

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table1').DataTable( {
        "searching": false,
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
         buttons: [
             {
                text: 'Update',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    alert( 'This is my button' );
                }
             }
         ]

    } );
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the data for the selected row.

```
$('#table1 tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
} );
```